# How do you trigger a CD pipeline dependent on a CI pipeline succeeding?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-delivery

I want:

- PipelineA builds and uploads an artifact, when that completes successfully
- PipelineB runs and downloads PipelineA's artifact

PipelineA's trigger:

```
trigger:   
    branches:
        include:
        - release/*
        - master
```

This works as expected, PipelineA will run and build an artifact whenever a code change is made.

PipelineB's trigger (does not work!)

```
trigger: none # important! we do not want to be deploying to environments without an artifact

resources: 
    pipelines:
    - pipeline: PipelineALocal # does not matter, only for pulling down local vars
      source: PipelineA # the exact name defined in ADO
      trigger: true # tried every variant under the sun to get this working but this pipeline will never run
```

I've tried every combination of triggers including the (apparently should always work `trigger: true`?) but nothing works. The pipeline never triggers.

Under `resources.pipelines.branches.include`, I've tried: `refs/heads/master`, `master`, `refs/heads/release/*`, `release/*` and everything in-between. With proper YAML formatting of course.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example) is very confusing, but I managed to figure out how to get the `runID` from a pipeline alias.

--

I've resorted to trying to go through the triggers UI and configure a PipelineB Build completion trigger based on PipelineA succeeding.

That only works for the master branch, so I cannot use `variables['Build.SourceBranch']` to determine if this is a staging or release build.

How do you trigger a CD pipeline dependent on a CI pipeline succeeding?

Comment: Is the build from PipelineA fully succeeding or partially succeeding?

Comment: Have you ever set up a trigger for the pipeline in the UI? (Edit -> Ellipsis -> Triggers)

Comment: Yes PipelineA's build succeeds.

--


I did use the ellipsis UI, and that works for `master`. But I need to also be able to control `release` pipelines too. `variables['Build.SourceBranch']` always becomes `master` in the CD pipeline which is no good.
 
Why would I do that when the pipelines are supposed to be fully configurable through Yaml in the first place? 

Comment: Hi @user5812916, how are things going? I noticed that there are some good suggestions in `@BartoszPelikan`'s answer. Please have a check with them.

Answer (score 0):

There are any circumstances of separation of these pipelines?

I use only one yml for CI and CD using stages and depend CD from success of CI stage:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...

- stage: CD
  dependsOn: CI
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...
```

---

**Edit2:**

I tried this

```yaml
trigger: none

resources: 
    pipelines:
    - pipeline: cd-test
      source: ci-pipeline
      trigger: true
```

on my project and this is working fine but you must remembet that trigger in `PipelineB` (in my case `ci-pipeline`) must be on `master` branch when I deleted them from `master` it was stop working.

---

**Edit1:**

To enable triggering from another pipeline you must go to `Edit Pipeline definition` -> `Triggers`
[image]

and set trigger:
[image]

Comment: It is best practice to separate the pipelines because the building may be for PR verification or, more importantly, generating a release artifact.

The release pipeline is separate so it can piggyback off of a successful build (that is intended for a release).

Comment: To achieve what you are about talking you can use stage `Conditions`. I'm not sure if it is possible in Azure DevOps to run two pipelines as completely separate files. Now I am really curious if it is possible. In all Microsoft documents, I only read about the `Stages` and `Conditions` and I have never heard such a case.

Comment: What? When you create a new pipeline it literally prompts a new file for a new pipeline.

Comment: Alright I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I've seen this doc 1000 times lol. Even copying their config identically it does not work

Comment: I figure out how to do this but for me this the pipeline which is triggered is running only for master

Comment: @denvercoder *"it is best practice to separate the pipelines"*. According to whom? I rarely recommend doing that. You can use conditions to specify stages or jobs that should run only during PR, or only when *not* triggered from a PR.

Comment: I fully agree with @daniel-mann, separate pipelines make it more complicated, as we can even see in the example above. Always we can use templates if yml file is going to be to large.